# Branch-and-bound based IP solver

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization, integer

I've written this rather naïve branch-and-bound based IP solver.

Are there any obvious JavaScript optimisations that could speed it up?  I am not looking for asymptotically better algorithms, just simple speed optimisations effective on problem sizes with 5-6 variables and `minSize` values up to about 500.

```
/** Represents a simple 1-dimensional 
 * IP (Integer Programming) problem.
 * @constructor
 * @param {Array<size: Number, cost: Number>} priceList
 *   List of costs for given sizes.
 *   Note that this list will be sorted by this constructor.
 */
function Prices (priceList) {
  this.prices = priceList;
  this.prices.sort (PriceCompare);
  this.minimise = PricesMinimise;
  this.pricesBB = PricesBB;
}

/** Solves the simple 1-dimensional IP problem:
 * Minimise Sum_i cost_i * x_i
 *    where Sum_i size_i * x_i >= minSize
 *      and cost_i, size_i are positive reals,
 *      and x_i is a nonnegative integer. (i = 0..prices.length - 1)
 *
 * cost_i = this.prices[i].cost and size_i = this.prices[i].size.
 *
 * @param {Number} minSize  The minimum size that must be supplied.
 * @return {xs: Array, cost: Number}  [x_0, x_1, ...] and total cost.
 */
function PricesMinimise (minSize) {
  this.minSize = minSize;
  this.incumbent = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  this.maxCost = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  var xsCost = this.pricesBB (0, 0, 0, 0);
  xsCost.xs.reverse ();
  return xsCost;
}

/** Solves a sub problem using only price list elements with
 * index >= i.  It uses instance fields
 * minSize: the minimum required size sum,
 * incumbent: lowest full solution cost seen so far,
 * maxCost: upper bound on full solution cost.
 * @param {Number} i        Minimum price list index.
 * @param {Number} sizeSum  Size sum already selected.
 * @param {Number} costSum  Cost sum already spent.
 * @param {Number} minCost  Lower bound on full solution cost in this
 *                          subtree.
 * @return {xs: Array, cost: Number}  A minimum candidate
 *   solution, or null if none better than the incumbent were
 *   found.
 */
function PricesBB (i, sizeSum, costSum, minCost) {
  var price = this.prices [i];
  var size = price.size;
  var cost = price.cost;
  var xReal = (this.minSize - sizeSum) / size;
  var x = Math.ceil (xReal);
  var localCostSum;
  if (size == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
    x = 1;
    size = 0; // Avoid NaN in recursive call
    localCostSum = cost;
  } else {
    localCostSum = costSum + cost * x;
    var localMinCost = costSum + cost * xReal;
    minCost = Math.max (minCost, localMinCost);
    if (localMinCost >= this.incumbent) return null;
  }
  this.maxCost = Math.min (this.maxCost, localCostSum);
  var localMin = {'xs': [x], 'cost': localCostSum};
  if (localCostSum < this.incumbent) this.incumbent = localCostSum;
  if (localCostSum == minCost) return localMin;
  if (i < this.prices.length - 1)
    for (x--; x >= 0; x--) {
      var xsCost =
        this.pricesBB (i + 1, sizeSum + size * x, costSum + cost * x, minCost);
      if (xsCost == null) continue;
      xsCost.xs.push (x);
      localMin = xsCost;
      if (localMin.cost == minCost) return localMin;
    }
  if (localMin.cost == this.incumbent)
    return localMin;
  else
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'll try to take a more serious look at this if it's still not answered when I have more time, but for starters, anywhere you can use "===" instead of "==" would be good. "==" performs type coercion in JS (which allows "5" == 5 to return true), whereas "===" does not.

Comment: To be honest, that code looks horrible, either clean it up or provide some tests, otherwise chances are **very** high that any attempt by us to optimize it, will break it.

Comment: Please provide the definition of PriceCompare and context for the optimization: which methods do you call, what does the data look like...

Comment: Ivo, I'd be happy to clean up the code if you explain me what you had in mind.  Especially, of course, if it would speed it up :-)

Comment: TheXenocide, will type coercion also incur a cost in places where the types are already identical?

Eric, sorry for leaving out PriceCompare---it compares two prices by comparing their cost per size.  Anyway, I wasn't really thinking of algorithmic optimisations, rather of JavaScript-related speedups.
To use this code, you first construct a Price object using new Price(...), then you call its minimise method.

Comment: @Ame That code's comments is incredibly abstract and inline comments in the function would help. I second supplying test cases showing the blackbox functionality of the function. Most likely the best way to optimise is to have a high level understanding of what your doing and telling you a better O(foo) algorithm.

Comment: @Ame it's hard to optimize JavaScript code out of the blue. Different browsers tend to be slow in different areas, and it rarely matters unless you repeat the same inefficient operation multiple times. So optimizing the algorithm is a safe way to optimize linearly in all browsers, and you need to benchmark in target browsers to identify specific bottlenecks.

Comment: @Raynos: I see what you mean; however, what I was really looking for were places where I used obviously inefficient JavaScript constructions, rather than improving the general complexity of the algorithm.  I would have thought this would not require understanding of the algorithm.

Comment: @Eric I see.  I didn't know that browsers are so different that there is no general advice on JavaScript constructions to avoid or to use.  Thanks!

Comment: Review your `for` loop and look at a negative `while` instead.  Basis of my comment here: http://blogs.sun.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a

Comment: @Mark: Interesting.  In your list I dont see any for loops using === or !==.  How much slower than the negative while loop would the following be?

for (var i = 0, l = length; i !== l; i++) { }

Comment: @Arne: not sure as I did not personally test all of his options.  Might be worth it to compare it specifically in your browser of choice using development tools however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowadays we have great tools at our disposal, one of them is [The Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) from Google, which is a tool for making JavaScript download and run faster.  It parses your JavaScript, analyzes it, removes dead code and rewrites and minimizes what's left. It also checks syntax, variable references, and types, and warns about common JavaScript pitfalls.

So, the [web version of Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com) gave me the following recommendations for your snippet:

1. Example, 
   `this.incumbent = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;`
   `this.maxCost = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;`
   **becomes** `this.maxCost = this.incumbent = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;`
2. Other obvious speed enhancements that can be automated with minification:

   - Use parameters as a variable instead of another var:
     <strike>`var`</strike> `minSize = this.pricesBB(0, 0, 0, 0);`
   - Reuse var's when they are longer in user in a function instead of declaring new ones
   - Shorten variable names (parsing speed issue)
   - `var price = this.prices [i];
     var size = price.size;` **becomes** `var price = this.prices[i], g = price.size;`

The full result of the Closure Compiler for your piece Javascript:

```
function Prices(c) {
  this.prices = c;
  this.prices.sort(PriceCompare);
  this.minimise = PricesMinimise;
  this.pricesBB = PricesBB
}
function PricesMinimise(c) {
  this.minSize = c;
  this.maxCost = this.incumbent = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  c = this.pricesBB(0, 0, 0, 0);
  c.xs.reverse();
  return c
}
function PricesBB(c, i, h, f) {
  var e = this.prices[c], g = e.size;
  e = e.cost;
  var a = (this.minSize - i) / g, d = Math.ceil(a), b;
  if(g == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
    d = 1;
    g = 0;
    b = e
  }else {
    b = h + e * d;
    a = h + e * a;
    f = Math.max(f, a);
    if(a >= this.incumbent) {
      return null
    }
  }
  this.maxCost = Math.min(this.maxCost, b);
  a = {xs:[d], cost:b};
  if(b < this.incumbent) {
    this.incumbent = b
  }
  if(b == f) {
    return a
  }
  if(c < this.prices.length - 1) {
    for(d--;d >= 0;d--) {
      b = this.pricesBB(c + 1, i + g * d, h + e * d, f);
      if(b != null) {
        b.xs.push(d);
        a = b;
        if(a.cost == f) {
          return a
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return a.cost == this.incumbent ? a : null
}
;
```